# Client-side js: check file encoding

Tags: javascript, utf-8, filereader

I have to validate on client side that my downloading file is UTF-8 encoded. How can I do it?
Maybe something with `FileReader.readAsArrayBuffer()`

Answer (score 0):

try this:

reader.readAsText(file, 'ISO-8859-1');

may be it will help to you.

Answer (score 0):

I happen to be doing some file upload operation and was facing problem with csv file with non-ascii character. However, using ISO-8859-1 solved my problem but not with utf-8 or utf-16. Here is my code snippet.

```
     function printTable(file) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.readAsText(file, 'ISO-8859-1');
        reader.onload = function (event) {
            var csv = event.target.result;
            var data = $.csv.toObjects(csv);
            var html = '';
            for (var row in data) {
                html += '<tr>\r\n';
                for (var item in data[row]) {
                    html += '<td>' + item + ':' + data[row][item] + '</td>\r\n';
                }
                html += '</tr>\r\n';
            }
            $('#contents').html(html);
        };
        reader.onerror = function () { alert('unable to read ' + file.fileName); };
    }
```

Now, I am getting those non-ascii characters when importing even though the csv file is not saved with utf-8 encoding.